# DAX formula to flag orders based on whether items are there or not

Tags: powerbi, dax

I have a situation where I need to flag `Order ID` if there is at least one non-null `Detail ID` for that order and say whether it's missing or not. If there is at least one non-null `Detail ID`, it will be "Not Missing". Otherwise, it will be "Missing". In my screenshot, `Calc Column` is what I'm trying to create.

[image: ![Example Data]][1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TyFl9.jpg)

Comment: Have you tried `ISBLANK()` or `LEN()` inside an `IF()`?

Comment: I can flag them at the Detail ID level using those functions but if I go one level up (Order level), it repeats the Order ID with both missing and not missing values.

Comment: Ah, I see what you mean and I've got an idea.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you can do is count the number of non-blank `Detail ID` values for each `Order ID` and if that value is positive, then return "Not Missing".

```
Calc Column =
VAR DetailCount =
    CALCULATE (
        COUNT ( Orders[Detail ID] ),
        ALL ( Orders ),
        Orders[Order ID] = EARLIER ( Orders[Order ID] )
    )
RETURN
    IF ( DetailCount > 0, "Not Missing", "Missing" )
```

The `EARLIER` refers to the earlier row context so that you're only matching against the same `Order ID` instead of the whole table.

Comment: That did it! Thank you :) Could you explain how Orders[Order ID] = EARLIER ( Orders[Order ID] ) work?

Comment: I'm taking the whole table (the `ALL` function removes the row context) and then filtering it down to the rows where the `Order ID` matches the one in the current row. The "in the current row" part is described by the row context, so the `EARLIER` function returns the `Order ID` in the context earlier in the evaluation. https://powerpivotpro.com/2012/03/the-correct-usage-of-earlier/